# Unknown Library refrences in a project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, shared-libraries

We received one demo project from one of our clients. We tried running it, but unfortunately couldn't run it. Reason being there are many libraries like **applicationinsights** , etc within the project which are no more available. We are totally unaware about these, also we tried adding them through nuggets ( console ) but couldn't install them in project. But another thing I would like to know is what is the use of these types of libraries? In an mvc project do we need **applicationinsights** because are client wants to connect it to azure services. Any help , information would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on Application Insights service. Whether you would need this or not in your application would entirely depend on you.

Comment: Read this post may help you https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-insights-overview/